# Anyone know where I can find a list of the top 100 or so music hits in SPANISH from each year starting at the 50s or 60?

Tags: playlists

(top 100 1951,top 100 1952..etc) all the way until 1980.

I am specifically looking for latino/latin music.  I've searched the Mexico google for the last few hours in spanish keywords but to no avail.  I've also scoured wikipedia and a ton of data seems to be missing.

If you find one that is not top 100 by each year (top 70, top 50, etc.), that's fine.

If no page is found, where can I go to pay someone to make such lists, preferably a spanish speaking site? (I am willing to pay a good amount)

Please redirect me to any useful sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best source will be *[Los 40 Principales](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Los_40)*, or as it's known now *Los 40*.

It started in Spain during the 60s as a 40 hits countdown and evolved to a broadcast network. Since their beginning they compiled a Top 40 of hits in **Spain**.

With Latin american countries you will find multiple problems:

- They didn't have something like *Billboard* that compiled charts using radio airtime and record sales. Sadly, it makes very difficult to find information about top songs year by year.
- There is a big difference of genres country to country. So you won't find a general Latin American Top 40 by year. Mexico was during the 50s more into *bolero/ranchera* while Colombia was more into *vallenato or cumbia*. It doesn't mean that Colombia didn't know about Mexican boleros because the film industry in Mexico exported its culture through movies with artists as Jorge Negrete or Pedro Infante.

Comment: I'm going to use Los 40 Principales.  Thank you.  However, is there not a Mexico bolero/ranchera top hits along with a cumbia/vallenato hits?  I would like to combine los 40 with another list.  Also, rock en espanol.  Please let me know if you know any of those sources.

Answer (score 2):

Latin America and Spanish speaking nations are not a single entity. Each nation is independent. You will never find all of them aggregated.

If you find such a list, it should include
For the 70's Almendra, and Pescado Rabioso, and Sui Géneris.
For the 80's Soda Stereo, Virus, Charly García, Spinetta, Fito Paez, Abuelos de la nada, Redonditos de Ricota.
For the 90's Redonditos de Ricota, Ratones Paranoicos, Bersuit.
For the 2000's Los Piojos, Bersuit, Indio Solari, Skay Beilinson.
For the 2010's Siamés, Octafonic, Triddana, Maxi Trusso, Poncho, 42 Decibel